# Is there a C++ CalDav protocol library to connect to iCloud//Yahoo  

Tags: c++, icloud, caldav

I have started working on C++ Windows application which needs to fetch Icloud and Yahoo Calendars by connecting to the CalDav servers.

Is there a C++ library that implements this protocol?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?  http://trac.mulberrymail.com/repos/browser#CICalendar/trunk/Source

Answer (score 1):

*Is there a C++ library that implements this protocol?*
There's always a number of good opensource libs that implement standardised protocols like CalDav.
They are best hunted on FOSS project hosts (with the help of Google).
Here is afew:-

- http://libcaldav.sourceforge.net/
- http://trac.mulberrymail.com/repos/wiki/icalendar
- https://code.google.com/p/kcaldav/ <- unmaintained but may be usefull
- http://www.zarafa.com/ <- you might want to extract the CalDav only code from this
- https://code.google.com/p/openconnector/ <- same as above

Comment: The trac.mulberrymail.com link is a dead link by now.